# Android TTS speech synthesis error when screen is lock

Tags: android, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I am writing an Android app that needs to speak using text-to-speech ([TTS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html)).

```
tts.speak("Some text", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null, UTT_ID);
```

This works perfectly fine when the screen is on.

If the screen is off & lock, the Activity will wake up the screen (upon creation) and show itself (intentional). This is accomplished with

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

And this works fine too.

However, when the Activity is created and shown when the screen had been off...text-to-speech will not create any sound.

Looking at log, I see

```
TTS     : synthesizeWithoutLoadingVoice() failed
```

Googling this error message gave nothing.
Anyone know what I did wrong here?

Comment: You'll need to post your code, if the answer below doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try recreating the TTS in the onResume function of your app. That is to move the init() function of TTS to onResume().

Comment: Thank you! This works.
In fact, initializing the TTS engine in onResume or onCreate (for my use case) works fine.

The issue before...was that I had created a singleton TTS object to be shared across many Activities. Apparently that object either got invalidated or got into a bad state once some of the activities were paused.

So, basically, you just need to reinitialize the TTS engine every time a new Activity comes into the foreground.